# Problema da parada pode ser resolvido na prática?

Tags: teoria-da-computação

O problema da parada pode ser explicado como: dado um programa e uma entrada para o mesmo, ele vai completar sua execução e retornar uma resposta ou entrará em um ciclo infinito?

Isso foi provado como indecidível por Turing, inquestionável. O ponto é: me ocorreu uma forma simples de resolver tal problema.

Se a cada estado de execução do programa eu fizer um dump completo da memória e dos registradores, terei o estado do programa em qualquer instante. A partir daí basta chegar se houve alguma repetição de estado. Como tudo que o programa pode fazer é transitar para o próximo estado baseado apenas no estado anterior, se o estado repetiu então é imediato inferir que o programa está entrando em um loop infinito.

A memória é finita, logo existe um número finito de estados. Qualquer programa que não termina vai eventualmente repetir um estado. Não estou dizendo que isso é viável, afinal em uma memória de quatro gigas temos no ao menos 2 elevado a 4000000000 estados. Nem sei quantos dígitos isso tem.

Minha pergunta é: o que está errado? Claramente o problema é indecidível. Onde esse método falha?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/64969

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A ideia é interessante, mas o problema da parada diz que dado um programa *qualquer* e uma entrada para o mesmo... Se você está limitando o seu programa a rodar em um ambiente de memória finita (seja 4GB), então você está necessariamente restringindo o escopo do problema original. Para o programa ser realmente arbitrário você precisa remover esta restrição, o que faz com que a sua solução finita (embora inviável, já que o seu número tem mais de um bilhão de dígitos) não se aplique ao caso geral.

Agora, sua pergunta é se para um caso específico de um programa ele pode ser resolvido "na prática". Na prática, você não tem onde armazenar todos os dumps de memória que a sua solução precisa, e não tem o tempo (quase) infinito que ela requer também :)

Comment: O problema deixa de ser indecidível mas continua absolutamente intratável

Answer (score 15):

Na verdade, sua solução não consegue pegar casos simples. Pois é, qualquer programa que altere seu estado sem voltar atrás não é detectado como possível causador de laço infinito.

Imagine o seguinte programa em Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
    while (true) {
      l.add(123);
    }
}
```

Cada momento em que for feito o dump, ele estará com um estado novo. Estando em um estado novo, seu algoritmo de verificar se ele entrou em algum estado previamente conhecido vai por água a baixo. Nada feito. Retirando limitações de memória e considerando endereçamento com bitagem variável/infinita, a lista ligada cresceria até o infinito sem se preocupar com outra coisa nesse mundo.

Creio que sua heurística entraria em um estado seguinte à análise estática do código. Se for fornecido simplesmente a caixa preta do programa, talvez não muito mais do que seu [autômato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260864/64969) em formato assembly-símile, aí teremos um problema maior. Quanto mais básica for a forma de representação do programa, quanto mais próxima for da [máquina de Turing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158043/64969), mais difícil será a análise estática.

Uma outra heurística (talvez até mais eficiente) que provedores de serviços computacionais usam é disponibilizar um `timeout` para a sua execução. Se você estiver lidando com um problema do dia-a-dia, muito provavelmente você estará lidando com um problema da classe P ou então alguma heurística para trazer uma resposta satisfatória mesmo que imperfeita, portanto você precisa rodar rápido.

Questões mais complexas (como isomorfismo de grafos ou mesmo prever a estrutura meta-estável de uma proteína dada sua sequência de aminoácidos) realmente exigem poder computacional maior e possivelmente a heurística do `timeout` daria falsos positivos para "execução eterna". Essa medida de segurança é fornecida em ambientes de computação de alto desempenho como o agendador de execuções SLURM, para evitar que alguém sem querer passe um caso impossível de ser resolvido e tome para si todo o poder computacional de um núcleo de pesquisa. Também é aplicada essa heurística em comunicação entre duas máquinas distintas, pois hipoteticamente você pode fornecer uma entrada que causaria a outra máquina a entrar em execução infinita, através do timeout de leitura e escrita do socket.

Answer (score 10):

Se a cada instrução do processador, você fizer um dump dos 4 Gb de memória (e também das caches, do disco e dos registradores), quaisquer programas que estejam rodando irão eventualmente repetir um estado e você consegue comprovar isso com o dump. Afinal de contas, se a memória tem um tamanho finito, logo a quantidade de estados existentes é finita. O problema da parada se aplica para os casos onde a memória é infinita, mas esse caso é o que tem memória finita.

O problema da parada é (teoricamente) solucionável nos casos onde a memória é finita fazendo exatamente isso que você propõe. No entanto, é preciso olhar esse "teoricamente" com bastante atenção.

No pior caso, você teria que percorrer todos os 2<sup>n</sup> estados de memória até ele repetir, onde n é o número de bits existentes na memória como um todo. Se *n* for um valor suficientemente pequeno (para algum dispositivo com uns poucos bytes de memória total), isso até que é viável. Para um computador típico de alguns gigabytes de memória, isso é totalmente inviável. Se considerarmos apenas os 4 Gb de memória e desconsiderarmos os discos, o número de estados existentes seria de 2<sup>34.359.738.368</sup> (4 Gb = 34.359.738.368 bits). Isso resulta em um número com mais de 10 bilhões de dígitos decimais!

Cada **bit** de memória existente **dobra** a quantidade de estados possíveis e consequentemente dobra o tempo e o consumo de energia necessário para percorrer todos esses estados. A cada byte de memória acrescentado, a quantidade de estados aumenta em 256 vezes. Agora, imagine ter 34.359.738.368 bits, cada um dobrando a quantidade de estados possíveis (isso são 4 Gb, e olhe que isso é só a memória principal de um computador já considerado limitado para os dias de hoje, além disso estamos desconsiderando os discos).

Você simplesmente não consegue percorrer todo esse montão de estados porque isso demorará um tempão e gastará muita energia. A física termodinâmica vai impôr barreiras antes que você possa terminar isso. Logo, uma dessas coisas acontece antes:

1. O computador é destruído por forças externas a ele.
2. [O Universo acaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe) antes de você percorrer todos os estados. Não sei se seria com o Big Crunch, o Big Rip, o Big Freeze, Big Bounce, Heat Death ou outra coisa. Mas qualquer que seja o caso, não seria bom para você. Isso implica na hipótese 1 acima.
3. Você consome toda a energia do universo a fim de criar e armazenar dumps de memória suficientes (ou mesmo se for só para manter o computador em funcionamento percorrendo todos esses estados). Isso implica na hipótese 2 acima que por sua vez implica na hipótese 1.

Assim, não é difícil se ver que com uma quantidade de memória suficiente, uma das três coisas enumeradas acima ocorreriam (e ocorreriam bem cedo!) nesse processo.